# MongoEngine: Close connection

Tags: python, connection, mongoengine, disconnect

I spent ages trying to find a simple example where MongoEngine was being used and a connection was being closed. Finally figured it out and posting my code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone else is searching I figured I'd give an alternate answer.

`close()` does not actually remove the connection from MongoEngine's connection list. This causes problems when trying to connect to a different database later on.

To solve this I used `mongoengine.connection.disconnect` (even though it's not listed in `__all__`). My code looks like this:

```
from mongoengine import connect
from mongoengine.connection import disconnect

db = connect(alias='some_alias')

{do stuff}

disconnect(alias='some_alias')
```

You can also leave the alias out as it will default to 'default' in both connect and disconnect.

Answer (score 8):

I thought `disconnect()` was supposed to be used initially, but it has been removed as a synonym for `close()`.

```
from mongoengine import connect

def main():

    #connect to db
    db_client = connect('my_db', host='localhost', port=27017)

    #close the connection
    db_client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: mongoengine maintainer here, use `disconnect` instead of close

Comment: That's not true, in the documentation:
```The :meth:`MongoClient.disconnect` method is removed; it was a  synonym for :meth:`~pymongo.MongoClient.close```

Answer (score 4):

It can be managed with Connection class like bellow. It creates connection with **__enter__** and closes it with **__exit__** method.

```
from mongoengine import connect
from app.config import config


class Connection:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = connect(host=config.mongo_url)
        return self.conn

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.conn.close()
```

Then you can use it with **"with"** statement.

```
from app.connection import Connection

with Connection():
     # do some stuff with db, connection will be closed after with statement
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

#### According to the mongoengine docs

```
Calling disconnect() without argument will disconnect the “default” connection
```

As pointed out in accepted answer, in some cases it is important to definine "alias" when using connect and disconnect.

#### Experiments without defining "alias"

In my case connecting with alias='testdb' and disconnecting without defining 'alias' worked well until I moved my db and backend inside docker. For some reason, when running tests with mongomock inside docker I got the following errors:

```
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: A different connection with alias `testdb` was already registered. Use disconnect() first
```

and

```
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: You have not defined a default connection
```

#### Solution

After defining alias='testdb' also when disconnecting, everything worked well